# How to auto switch to preferred wireless network

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have two wireless networks (fiber router & phone). I want to

1. Set the Router wireless as primary
2. When the primary network is off(Power failure) autoswitch to secondary.
3. When the primary network is on switch back to primary.

Is there a configuration setting that allows this? if not what are the possible solution?

If nothing is available, I am thinking of a cron job which

1. Check whether laptop is on battery power or AC
2. Which is the network in use.
3. If AC & phone network scans for the router network and switches...

Comment: Usually a _network manager_ program can do this for you.

Comment: In my experience the network manager automatically switches from a wireless n/w to a wired n/w, but I was not able to find any setting to make it switch from one wireless network to another.

Comment: In better network-manager you can adjust the preference, often with a "priority"  value. (`kcmshell5 kcm_networkmanagement` for example uses a "priority" value range from -100 to +100, where higher value means higher priority) Read the manual of your network-manager and you'll probably find something like that.